# Button loses action when selected with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate a login flow with Selenium using Python. When I manually go through the flow everything works as expected. I can load the webpage with the webdriver, but once I select the username field I see the following error in the browser console when trying to submit it:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of null
```

I've tried navigating to the page via Selenium, then manually filling in the username and it will submit successfully. However, if my script navigates to the page and then selects the target field, the error will occur on submitting the field, even if I fill and submit it manually while the script waits. I know that the field is being targeted successfully, because the send_keys call fills it in correctly. Selecting any element on the page via Selenium causes the same issue. It seems that this only affects controls that trigger a page update without routing; buttons that link to other pages still function as expected.

My code is very basic at this stage and looks roughly like this:

```
chrome_options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.targetwebsite.com")

# Executing this line, or anything using a locator, seems to cause the issue
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "usernameTextBox")))

element.send_keys("username")
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

The input field that I am targeting:

```
<input _ngcontent-c7 appformatter class="text_box input_box ng-pristine ng-invalid remote-accessable focusable ng-touched" id="usernameTextBox" type="text" aria-label="username">
```

I tried swapping out Chromedriver and using Geckodriver with Firefox instead, but had the same issue.
Any idea what could be causing this? I've never seen anything like this before working with Selenium.

Comment: Does your page load. I tried to navigate the url manually , I get site cant be reached error

Comment: can you pls provide html code . looks to me it does not identify the username text box

Comment: @Sonali That is not the real website, I used a place holder for privacy reasons since this is a business project. The real page loads and runs successfully when navigated to manually. I will edit the post to add an HTML snippet.

Comment: @Sonali The locator is not the issue, since when I send keys to the element they fill in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to interact with element using JavaScript and see if you get same behaviour. Do something like this:

```
script = "arguments[0].value=" + username         #if element is input type
script = "arguments[0].innerText=" + username     #if element is button
driver.execute_script(script,element)
```

For Enter key, check if you can do it with button click. Otherwise use same as you are doing with selenium.

Comment: I tried using the javascript executor and have the same issue. Simply selecting the control, even without sending keys to it, breaks the submission.